# Preview text scaled differently from the mobile display

Tags: android

I am new to android studio so I am not sure what I am doing wrong but in content_main.xml file, my preview of the layout seems fine but when I run the program on a virtual device the components are scaled differently. Another thing is the message button is not scaled differently (since I guess it's on the activity_main.xml file after the update) but only the components I added in the content file.

Here are the pictures.
[design page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSpDE.png)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtTxtFirstName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="First Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtTxtLastName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:hint="Last Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edtTxtFirstName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edtTxtFirstName"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtTxtFirstName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtTxtEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edtTxtLastName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edtTxtLastName"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtTxtLastName" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:onClick="onRegisterBtnClick"
    android:text="Register"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edtTxtEmail"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edtTxtEmail"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtTxtEmail" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtFirstName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:text="First Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btn_test"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn_test"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_test" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLastName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="Last Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtFirstName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtFirstName"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtFirstName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="62dp"
    android:text="Email"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtLastName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtLastName"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtLastName" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[display on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwrZE.png)

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a lot of huge margins. try to decrease margins of the textViews.
for instance :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtFirstName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="First Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btn_test"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn_test"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_test" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLastName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:text="Last Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtFirstName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtFirstName"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtFirstName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:text="Email"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtLastName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtLastName"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtLastName" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have made some modifications to your code.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtTxtFirstName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="First Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtTxtLastName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:hint="Last Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtTxtFirstName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtTxtEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtTxtLastName" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:onClick="onRegisterBtnClick"
    android:text="Register"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtTxtEmail" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtFirstName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="First Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtLastName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLastName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="Last Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtEmail" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="Email"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope this helps........

Feel free to ask for clarifications

Comment: But why is the preview different from the actual display?

Comment: @user12308200 You set your layout to work previously by setting _margins_ that worked for the preview screen size. But for different screen size, screen width and height may change and old margins may not be valid anymore. That is where `ConstraintLayout` comes in handy. It aligns views based on `Constraints`. This can overcome the limitation I mentioned before. Constraints are relative but fixed margins and view sizes may not be effective for different screen sizes. Hope this makes sense.....

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap root view with a `ScrollView` and constraint `end` and `start` of last `TextView` to the parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtTxtFirstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtTxtLastName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:hint="Last Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edtTxtFirstName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edtTxtFirstName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtTxtFirstName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtTxtEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edtTxtLastName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edtTxtLastName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtTxtLastName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:onClick="onRegisterBtnClick"
        android:text="Register"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edtTxtEmail"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edtTxtEmail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtTxtEmail" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFirstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:text="First Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btn_test"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn_test"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLastName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Last Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtFirstName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtFirstName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtFirstName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Email"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtLastName" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: But what's the reason for the display incompatibility? It is a bug?

Comment: No. You constraint `end` and `start` of last `textView` to another `textView`.

Comment: If you get your answer, please give green check mark.

Comment: I did constraint end and start of last textView to another textView and that's what the video I followed said. So... I am not sure... the below answer gives a different response so I don't know whats really right

Comment: Any convenience. But keep in mind that tutorial video content isn't always the right thing to do.